# Как реализовать такую вещь

Tags: php

Допустим есть кнопка на странице, как сделать так чтобы при нажатие она подключалось к базе данных. т.е не как прописать подключение, а как скрипт коннекта связать с кнопкой?

Comment: Видимо так же, как и любое другое действие завязать на кнопку.

Comment: Материала, объясняющего основы php, mysql и html с кнопками, в интернете навалом, с чем возникли проблемы?

Answer (score 3):

событие click. А в нем $.get, $.post. В опциях прописать урл где будет php вызов запроса в базу данных
пример.

```
$('#mybutton').on('click', function(){
    $.post('/sqlquery', function(data){
        //data возврат данных из базы
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Кнопка - на клиенте, в браузере. БД как правило на сервере.

План:

1. **На клиенте**. По событию `onclick` на клиенте вызывается функция JavaScript, которая в свою очередь делает асинхронный запрос AJAX на сервер по определенному URL, при необходимости также можно передать параметры

```html
<button onclick="CallAsyncRequest()">Соединиться с БД</button>

<script>
  function CallAsyncRequest() {
    $.post("ajax.php", {
        param1: 123,
        param2: 456
      }

      function(data) {
        $("#requestResult").html(data);
      });
  }
</script>
```

Для AJAX удобно использовать JQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ но можно и стандартными средствами JavaScript это сделать. В примере JQuery.

Параметры передаются обычным объектом JS, в примере это param1 со значением 123 и param2 со значением 456. Количество и формат - любые.

2. **На сервере**. Нужно написать скрипт подключения к БД и выполнению всех необходимых действий для твоей задачи, назвать его так же как на клиенте (`ajax.php` в примере) и сделать так, чтобы он отдавал результат в понятном для клиента виде (можно текстом, можно JSON или как-то еще)

```php
/* ajax.php */
$param1 = $_POST['param1']; // 123
$param2 = $_POST['param2']; // 456

$sql = '...'; // Формируем запрос на основании полученных параметров

db_connect();
$data = db_query($sql);
while ($row = db_fetch($data)) {
    print ToHtml($row); // Выводим результат в понятном для клиента виде
}
db_disconnect();
```

Осторожно, это псевдокод!

То, что отдал этот скрипт на выход, клиент получит в переменной `data` у себя в AJAX-ответе. Там же можно сделать парсинг и необходимые действия в зависимости от результата и ответа.